# VB6 creates corrupt compiles...?

Tags: vb6

I have known for a while that VB6 is trouble, but what can I do - I have a legacy system to maintain and it still being developed here and there.

And I had the weirdest thing ever happen to me with VB6 just now.

Compiled a new version of our application. Tested it - it worked.

Deployed to a client production site. Application keeps crashing! When? When the user clicks anywhere inside a DHTMLEdit control that we have in a specific window. Or sometimes even on the window that contains it.

Now, I've had this before and the solution was always very cryptic. So I tried the following: incremented the project's revision number by 1, recompiled, and guess what?

Works perfectly.

I cannot show code because we are talking about 50,000 lines of code here, and there is no specific code called when clicking the DHTMLEdit control, the form, whatever.

I'm just wondering if anyone else had encountered this oddity.

Comment: How did you deploy your compiled application? If using any kind of installer, then probably some components were not updated before incrementing version number. (We here have used VB6 for many years; only problems with compiling were few cases, when we selected some optimizations in project properties, otherwise no glitches. There have been numerous installation problems of course.)

Comment: @Arvo - thanks for commenting. The program uses many external dependencies but we did not change them, so we only deployed the main .exe file. This is very weird, I've been using it for years and this has never happened before.

Comment: This could be some [memory, disk, other hardware] glitch while compiling then. Sure you have to pay attention to jmoreno answer either - nothing is guaranteed in software world :)

Comment: Without the error message noone can say anything. Nothing you have said would lead one to think it's a VB6 problem. VB was the most popular language ever.

Answer (score 2):

The VB6 compiler is not a deterministic compiler and does not produce anything near consistent output.  IOW, while fixing your bug is not by design, the fact that it can produce such behavior is.

But even in deterministic compilers, making a small change can sometimes "fix" (aka hide) bugs that are triggered by memory alignments, or variable initialition

Comment: Thanks for this comment. So this is actually something that can just happen? Is there any way to tell except before shipping the product, except testing on several machines?

Comment: No, test on different machines, and test the version you intend to deploy -- a recompile with no code changes will radically modify the generated output (your program).  As a side note, I would consider 50k LOC well within the "it can and should be migrated if we are using it" realm.  I know nobody likes to have something done when there's no end user visible benefit, but i'd recommend it if at all possible.

Comment: @jmoreno, care to present some links to substantiate your claims? Using binary compatibility for components we here haven't seen "radically modified" results, but we have not analyzed so deeply either.

Comment: @jmoreno - you are absolutely right. I would love to migrate to VB.Net but we tried this before, and got a project with around 6,000 errors (not warnings, errors).

Comment: @Arvo: I'm not sure what you are asking for.  Functionally, it is supposed to be the same, but any diff tool will show that at the binary level, it's different.

Comment: @user884248: that doesn't suprise me, but most of them should be simple to fix.  For instance using the DataField, you can switch that to  Tag or create a component that allows you to fake it.  Hundreds or even thousands of such errors can be fixed at once.

Comment: @jmoreno - I will probably start working on this conversion project in a few days. Will the love and fond memories I have of VB6, it IS time to move on.